# SMB/CIFS URL not working in Android browser. How to open SMB shared files and folders in Android browser

Tags: networking, browser

I'm sharing some folders and files from windows in my LAN. I can access the files using ES-explorer and X-plorer apps. What I want is to open the folder in browser using URL. All laptop browsers can open the folder. The URL is like (file://sarath-69/e/), but android browsers cant open. I tried this way too (file:///sarath-69/e/) and I tried replacing file to smb, like (smb://sarath-69/e/), (smb://192.168.0.111/e/), (smb://null:@192.168.0.111/e/), (\sarath-69\e). Nothing works. Please help to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know none of the common web browsers include support for SMB/CIFS (on any platform). Even the FTP protocol is removed from more and more browsers. If you want to access files from a server run an HTTP(S) server on that server for providing the files. Or use an app that contains an Samba-client to copy files to your Android phone.

Comment: @Robert I checked with 2 browsers, EDGE and Chrome. Both are working. I can access file:// url in laptop browsers. But not working in android.

Comment: I was talking about SMB access. If you use file:// protocol then resolution of the path is forwarded to the OS, but Android has no built-in SMB support. Additionally file:// protocol  is disabled on Android web browsers for security reasons.

Comment: @Robert Is't it possible then? To open in android browsers? Or any other alternative way to open in browser? I mean like disabling the security.